# How to make single prediction from bagging model

Tags: python, scala, machine-learning, supervised-learning

I have the following line of code:

```
# Setting the values ​​for the number of folds

num_folds = 10
seed = 7

# Separating data into folds

kfold = KFold(num_folds, True, random_state = seed)

# Create the unit model (classificador fraco)

cart = DecisionTreeClassifier()

# Setting the number of trees

num_trees = 100

# Creating the bagging model

model = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator = cart, n_estimators = num_trees, random_state = seed)

# Cross Validation

resultado = cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv = kfold)

# Result print

print("Acurácia: %.3f" % (resultado.mean() * 100))
```

This is a ready-made code that I got from the internet, which is obviously predefined for testing my cross-validated TRAINING data and knowing the accuracy of the bagging algorithm.

I would like to know if I can apply it to my TEST data (data without output 'Y')

The code is a bit confusing and I can't model it.

I'm looking for something like:

```
# Training the model

model.fit(X, Y)

# Making predictions

Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

I want to use the trained bagging model on top of the training data in the test data and make predictions but I don't know how to modify the code

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `scala` or `big-data` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed). Also, please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code, so the comments are not displayed as unnecessary bold stuff in the text (done it for you this time).

Answer (score 0):

You have everything to predict new data already. I am providing a small example with toy data and comments to make it clear.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier

cart = BaggingClassifier()
X_train = [[0, 0], [1, 1]] # training data
Y_train = [0, 1] # training labels

cart.fit(X_train, Y_train) # model is trained

y_pred = cart.predict([ [0,1] ]) # new data
print(y_pred)

# prints [0], so it predicts the new sample (0,1) as 0 class
```